# Proving $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=l\Rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a^2_n=l^2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$$a_n\ge0, l\ge0$$If $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=l$$
Then $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a^2_n=l^2$$

Comment: Your notation is wrong.  You could write $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \ell$, or you could write $a_n \to \ell$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: ... or sometimes $a_n {{\longrightarrow} \atop {n \to \infty}} \ell$

Comment: But don't mix $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ and $\to \ell$.

Comment: $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous. QED.

Comment: yuvalz:l Do you plan to correct the $\lim\ldots\to\ldots$ misprints in the title and in the text of the question?

Comment: Oh, I didn't seem to understand what the problem was till now. Right on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a trick, which will help you solve this problem.

$$a_n^2 - l^2 = (a_n - l)^2 + 2l(a_n - l)$$
using this you should be able to show that $a_n^2 - l^2 \rightarrow 0$.

EDIT: To elaborate further, by the triangle inequality we now know that 
$$\lvert a_n^2 - l^2\rvert \leq \lvert (a_n - l)^2 \rvert + \lvert 2l(a_n-l)\rvert \hspace{10mm} (1)$$
So we just need to show that each of the two terms on the right get small as $n$ gets large. You should be able to make both of them small by using the fact that $a_n \rightarrow l$.

FINAL EDIT: To see a complete proof. Fix $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $N_0$ so that for $n\geq N_0$, $$\lvert a_n - l\rvert \leq \sqrt{\epsilon};$$ and $N_1$ large so that  for $n\geq N_1$, $$\lvert a_n - l \rvert \leq \frac{1}{\lvert 2 l \rvert} \epsilon.$$Then if $n\geq\max(N_0,N_1)$, the inequality (1) above gives us $$\lvert a_n^2 - l^2 \rvert \leq \epsilon + \epsilon = 2 \epsilon$$
and since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary we conclude that $\lvert a_n^2 - l^2\rvert \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: I don't get what you are saying. Can you please try to clarify?

Comment: @yuvalz I've edited to include a little more information, let me know if it helps or you would like me to clarify further.

Comment: Why rely on some algebraic specificities of the problem, while it has a completely general solution?

Comment: Can I simply say, basen on: $a_n\rightarrow l$ for $n> N_0$. That for $\epsilon>0$: $|a_n^2-l^2|<\epsilon \Leftrightarrow -\epsilon<l^2-l^2=0<\epsilon$ ?

Comment: @yuvalz, what you should do is fix an $\epsilon$, choose $N_0$ large enough so that both $\lvert (a_n - l) \rvert ^2$ and $\lvert 2l(a_n - l) \rvert$ are less than $\epsilon$. Which you can do because $a_n - l \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not a native english speaker. What do you mean by fix an $\epsilon$?

Comment: @yuvalz choose any small number, and call it $\epsilon$. Then choose $N_0$ large so that for $n\geq N_0$ we have $\lvert(a_n - l)\rvert^2$ and $\lvert 2l(a_n - l)\rvert$ are both less than $\epsilon$. Then, since we do this for any small number $\epsilon$, we get that $a_n^2 - l^2 \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @DevenWare Ok. Can you explain why replacing the $a_n$ with $l$ is invalid in this case?

Comment: @yuvalz I'm not quite sure what you mean. We don't ever replace $a_n$ with $l$, we just say that eventually $a_n$ is very close to $l$.

Comment: @DevenWare I've been told that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n\rightarrow l$. Why can't I use it to say $a_n^2-l^2=l^2-l^2$?

Comment: @yuvalz $a_n \rightarrow l$ this is true, but this means that $a_n$ is eventually very close to $l$, not that $a_n$ is eventually $l$ itself, which your equality implies. I advise you to read up a little on limits and hopefully this will make more sense.

Comment: @DevenWare Can I just ask of you one last thing? Can you please complete your proof, so I'll see how it should look?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since $a_n \to l$, there is a $n_1$ such that
$|a_n-l| < 1$ for $n > n_1$.

So, for $n > n_1$, 
$|a_n^2-l^2| = |(a_n-l)(a_n+l)|
< |a_n-l|(2|l|+1)
$.

Let $n_2$ be such that
$n_2 > n_1$ and
$|a_n-l| < \epsilon/(2|l|+1)$
for $n > n_2$.
Then $|a_n^2-l^2| < \epsilon$
for $n > n_2$,
so $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n^2 = l^2$.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n^2\not\rightarrow l^2$$
Exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that: $$|n^2-l^2|\ge\epsilon \Leftrightarrow l^2-\epsilon\ge n^2 \ge l^2 + \epsilon$$

Left side of the equation is false, because if it were true, $\epsilon<0$. Which is false.

Right side is false because:$$n^2-l^2\ge\epsilon \Leftrightarrow -l^2 \ge \epsilon-n^2 \ge 0$$

Which is again false, because $n,l\ge0$

EDIT: If this is wrong, please let me know why.